# How Can I Find the Length of a Space in TeX?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I have implemented the horrific document

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\testspace}[1]{\hspace*{\fill}\(\vert\)\hspace*{\fill}\\
                           \null\space\(\vert\)\hspace*{3.3pt plus #1pt}\break}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\(\vert\)\space\(\vert\)\\
\(\vert\)\hspace{3.3pt}\(\vert\)\\
\testspace{1.665}
\end{document}
```

This allows me to visually examine each vertical bar to see which ones line up the best, and therefore discover how much stretch an individual control space has. I estimate the width of a space to be about 3.3pt plus 1.665pt, however, I can't shake the feeling that this is awful. Nevertheless, TeX (and I think it is TeX and not LaTeX) will not let me use `\the\space`. How should I figure out the length of a single space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve length of a character](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79393/retrieve-length-of-a-character)

Comment: Surely you don't just want the length of a space. What are you going to do with that length?

Comment: @MaartenDhondt I think this is slightly different, as `\widthof{\space}` gives 5.0pt, which is considerably larger than a single space, and has no stretch besides. I have no idea how the `\widthof` macro works, and I won't hazard any guesses.

@Werner I am mostly just curious, but it came up when I was trying to make a space that would be the width of a space plus \fill.

Comment: @Programman: You can measure the width of a space in `pt`s and use that measurement. The rubber length doesn't give the real width when used within some other context; just the width that it could possible be between.

Comment: @Werner I understand how rubber lengths work (I read at least the beginning bits of the TeXbook) but you don't specify how to measure the length of the space. Regardless of any of this, I have already accepted an answer.

Comment: note `\space` is not a "control space" (the`\ ` primitive) it is simply a macro that expands to a space, `\widthof{\space}` is same as `\widthof{ }`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The width of normal space depends on current font. There are global metric items in each font called `\fontdimen`. The `\fontdimen2` includes the basic width of normal space, `\fontdimen3` includes value atfer `plus` and `\fontdimen4` includes value after `minus`. The `\fontdimen7` includes additional space used when `\spacefactor\ge 2000`.

Because the `\font` primitive used in the context `\fontdimen<number>\font` denotes the current font (and no normal declaration primitive), we can print
the values of normal space by the code:

```
\message{space: \the\fontdimen2\font\space 
   plus \the\fontdimen3\font\space minus \the\fontdimen4\font}
```

Computer Modern roman at 10 pt gives the following result:

```
space: 3.33333pt plus 1.66666pt minus 1.11111pt
```

And you can use `\hskip` primitive for creating normal space by

```
\hskip \fontdimen2\font plus\fontdimen3\font minus\fontdimen4\font
```

but this is only for illustration purposes. Normal people use `\space`or `\`  (control space).

EDIT: The normal space doesn't generate the space mentioned by `\hskip` above at all circumstances, because there are many exceptions. If the register `\spaceskip` is nonzero then `\fontdimen`s are not used but `\spaceskip` register is used. Moreover, if `\xspaceskip` is nonzero and the current `\spacefactor\ge 2000` then `\xspaceskip` is used.

There are two differences between `\`  (control space) and `\space` (or normal space between words, token of catcode 10):

- `\space` is ignored in vertical mode but `\`  in vertical mode starts horizontal mode.
- `\space` respects the current `\spacefactor` but `\`  does the same as `\space` when `\spacefactor=1000`.

Finally, what does mean that *the space respects current `\spacefactor`*. Let f=`\spacefactor/1000` and b is basic width of the space, p is plus value and m is minus value. Then p is modified by p:=p*f and m is modified by m:=m/f and b is kept unchanged. But, if `\spacefactor\ge2000` then b:=b+`\fontdimen7` (or `\xspaceskip` is used if it is nonzero).

I add an example from my TeXbook naruby, page 105: Suppose the normal space (when `\spacefactor=1000`) as 10pt plus10pt minus10pt. When `\spacefactor=600` then
the space 10pt plus 6pt minus16.666pt is inserted, when `\spacefactor=1500` then 10pt plus15pt minus6.666 is inserted. Finally when `\spacefactor=3000` then 10pt+`\fontdimen7` plus 30pt minus 3.333pt is inserted.

Normally, `\spacefactor` is 1000, but in some languages the `\nonfrenchspacing` macro sets special `\sfcodes` to several characters. The `\spacefactor` is set to the `\sfcode` value of the last typeset character in horizontal mode. (There is an exception when `\spacefactor<1000` and `\sfcode>1000`. Then new `\spacefactor=1000`.) For example plain TeX sets `\sfcode` of period, question and exclamation mark to 3000, comma to 1250, semicolon to 1500 and colon to 2000.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88991/what-does-different-fontdimennum-mean

Comment: Yes thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Programman OK. Maybe it would be better to change the LaTeX to TeX in the title of your post.

Comment: @wipet I'm always hesitant to refer to TeX instead of LaTeX, but I think in this case its definitely TeX through and through. I will take your suggestion.