# Optimal subfigure width to span \textwidth

Tags: graphics

In this example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{c}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I chose the `subfigure` `width` equally 1/3 with the rationale that the figure span `\textwidth` exactly. From the result,

[image]

one can deduce that there is some overhead.

How do I optimally chose `subfigure` `width` so that the figure span `textwidth` exactly for N = 2, 3, 4, ... `subfigures`?

Comment: Real quick: all four `\centering` directives may be omitted.

Comment: You might  use the `floatrow` package and use  `\floatsetup[figure]{floatrowsep = none}.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is happening is that between each subfigure you have a new line that, for TeX, is exactly the same thing as a space. So what you have is three subfigures with two spaces in between. To fix it, add a `%` after each subfigure so that TeX will not consider it as a space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering% < useless
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{a}
  \end{subfigure}% < HERE 
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering% < useless
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{b}
  \end{subfigure}% < AND HERE
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering% < useless
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{c}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## Edit:

Since my answer was chosen even with all the other answers down here, I felt the need to add a few explanations for the future generations ;)

## Why `3 * 0.33\textwidth` does not fit in `\textwidth`?

Firstly, as I said above, the major problem was that when TeX reads either a `space` or a `new line` character, it understands both as a `space`. The rule is different for multiple `space`s or `new lines`. Multiple `space`s are treated by TeX as a single `space` and multiple `new line`s are treated by TeX as a paragraph ending. For example, if you compile this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
This is written
on      several
separate  lines
separated    by
a    new   line
character    or
by       spaces.


But when processed by \TeX, the result is two normal paragraphs!
\end{document}
```

you get this:

[image: The code above compiled]

This is quite obvious when writing only text, like in the example above. But the same applies when you are using figures. If you insert a `new line` between consecutive `\includegraphics` or `subfigure` environments, TeX will treat them as spaces!

In Viesturs' MWE, the subfigure environments are separated by `new line`s, which are treated by TeX as spaces.

To check the effect of the spaces in Viesturs' MWE, we can first measure the size of `\textwidth` with:

```
textwidth: \the\textwidth
```

and we get [image: Textwidth], thus the width of the subfigures is `0.33\textwidth`, which is exactly `113.85pt`.

Furthermore, we can [measure the space of the current font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229642/134574) using:

```
space: \the\fontdimen2\font\space plus \the\fontdimen3\font\space minus \the\fontdimen4\font
```

and we get [image: Space]. For TeX, this means that the space is `3.333pt` wide, but can be stretched by `1.666pt` or shrinked by `1.111pt`.

So, assuming that TeX will shrink the space as far as it can to try to fit the three `subfigure`s in a single line, the layout would have three figures of `113.85pt`, and two spaces of `3.333pt minus 1.111pt` (`= 2.222pt`). So the with of the contents is `3 * 113.85pt + 2 * 2.222pt = 345.994pt`, Which is `0.994pt` larger than the available `\textwidth`. Thus TeX will give up on putting it in one line and break the line before inserting the third subfigure!

But Phelype, how do I fix this?!?!

Well, Jimmy, another couple of things about TeX is that:

1. After TeX sees a `%` sign, it ignores everything that comes after it on the current line. This is why commenting works this way in TeX (and most programming languages, actually). But for the problem we're facing now, this is why the `%` sign makes TeX ignore the `new line` character between each `subfigure`.
2. TeX ignores leading `space`s! So the indentation before the following `\begin{subfigure}` is also ignored!

So, as far as TeX is concerned, this:

```
  \end{subfigure}% < HERE 
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
  \end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
  %              ^ No spaces!!!
```

and observe that the second one does not have any `space` between the `subfigure`s. Now, if we do the previous calculation without the spaces, we have `3 * 113.85pt = 341.55pt`, which fits in the current `\textwidth`!

This may seem obvious to some, but for starters it's tricky to promptly see why `3 * 0.33\textwidth` does not fit in `\textwidth`. A few months ago I frequently found myself naively changing `0.33\textwidth` to `0.329\textwidth` to make the figures fit on one line :P

Disclaimer: All the above is valid in normal typesetting mode. In verbatim, math, or other special environments the rules are different!

Comment: To reduce code clutter, you may wish to remove the three `\centering` directives contained inside the `subfigure` environments.

Answer (score 8):

> How to optimally chose `subfigure` widths so that the figure spans `\textwidth` exactly, for N = 2, 3, 4, ... `subfigure` environments?

- First off, note that all four `\centering` directives in your code may (and, in fact, should!) be omitted.
- Second, assuming you wish to leave a bit of whitespace between adjacent images, you should change the relative widths for *three* side-by-side subfigures from `0.33\textwidth` to something like `0.3\textwidth` or `0.31\textwidth`. Similarly, use `0.23\textwidth` or `0.24\textwidth` for *four* side-by-side subfigures, and `0.48\textwidth` for *two* side-by-side subfigures.
- Finally, use `\hfill` directives to maximize the separation between the subfigures placed on a line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.31\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{a}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill%  % <-- \hfill is new
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.31\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{b}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill%  % <-- \hfill is new
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.31\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{c}
  \end{subfigure}

\bigskip\bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{dd}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{ee}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{f\kern0ptf}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{gg}
  \end{subfigure}

\caption{Seven subfigures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The following uses [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to automate the process of specifying the number of elements to distribute evenly across `\textwidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,tabularx}

\newenvironment{distsubfig}[1]
  {\noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{@{} *{#1}{X} @{}}}
  {\endtabularx\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{distsubfig}{3}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{a}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{b}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{c}
  \end{distsubfig}

  \bigskip

  \begin{distsubfig}{5}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{a}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \subcaption{b}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \subcaption{c}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{e}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \subcaption{f}
  \end{distsubfig}
  \begin{distsubfig}{4}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \subcaption{g}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{h}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \subcaption{i}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \subcaption{j}
  \end{distsubfig}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `distsubfig` environment takes a single argument: the number of subfloats to distribute evenly across `\textwidth`; alternatively, the number of `X`-columns to use in a `tabularx`. The gap between the subfloats are `\tabcolsep`, just like in any `tabular` environment (and can be changed).

Comment: +1. For the benefit of those readers who are unfamiliar with some of the parameters of LaTeX's tabular-like environments, you may want to (a) mention the default value of `\tabcolsep` and (b) offer a suggestion (e.g., `\setlength{\tabcolsep}[...}` how one might change the value of this parameter.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version where you just need to specify the number of subfigures per row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\minsubgap}
\newlength{\maxsubgap}
\setlength{\minsubgap}{3pt}  % set to suit
\setlength{\maxsubgap}{12pt} % set to suit

\newlength{\viesturssubfigurewidth}
\newlength{\viesturssubfiguregap}

\newenvironment{bunchofsubfigures}[1] % #1 = images per row
 {%
  \setlength{\viesturssubfiguregap}{%
    \dimexpr\minsubgap+(\maxsubgap-\minsubgap)*2/(#1)\relax
  }%
  \setlength{\viesturssubfigurewidth}{%
    \dimexpr(\textwidth-\viesturssubfiguregap*(#1-1))/(#1)\relax
  }
  \setlength{\leftskip}{-0.1pt plus 1fil}%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{0pt}%
 }
 {{\parfillskip=-0.1pt plus 1fil\par}}
\newcommand{\viesturssub}[2]{% #1 = subcaption, #2 = image name
  \subcaptionbox{#1}{\includegraphics[width=\viesturssubfigurewidth]{#2}}%
  \hspace{\viesturssubfiguregap}\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{bunchofsubfigures}{2}
\viesturssub{Caption}{example-image}
\viesturssub{Caption}{example-image}
\viesturssub{Caption}{example-image}
\end{bunchofsubfigures}

\caption{Full caption}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{bunchofsubfigures}{3}
\viesturssub{Caption}{example-image}
\viesturssub{Caption}{example-image}
\viesturssub{Caption}{example-image}
\viesturssub{Caption}{example-image}
\viesturssub{Caption}{example-image}
\viesturssub{Caption}{example-image}
\end{bunchofsubfigures}

\caption{Full caption}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{bunchofsubfigures}{5}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\end{bunchofsubfigures}

\caption{Full caption}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{bunchofsubfigures}{6}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\end{bunchofsubfigures}

\caption{Full caption}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{bunchofsubfigures}{7}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\end{bunchofsubfigures}

\caption{Full caption}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{bunchofsubfigures}{8}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\viesturssub{}{example-image}
\end{bunchofsubfigures}

\caption{Full caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `\maxsubgap` is used between two figures per row; the gap goes asymptotically to `\minsubgap` as the number of figures per row increases. Choose both values to suit your needs.

[image]