# Three images on one line using subfigure

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption

I'm trying to put 3 images into one figure on one line. I have done the following approach:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{1}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:3_classes}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{1}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:5_classes}
  \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{1}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:6_classes}
  \end{subfigure}\par\medskip
    \caption{This is a test.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

The image 1.png is available on onedrive: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlkQuYgB1McYg8xUxUYxiZlhf9b6Ww

The problem is that I'm getting the following results. The captions are ok but the images are really small and somehow left alligned. I would like to have the images as large as possible so that they fit on one line.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Once you enter a `\begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}`, `\textwidth` becomes `0.33\textwidth` so you are effectively doing `0.33*0.33\textwidht`. Remove the `0.33` from the `\includegraphics`. You can use as example the first batch of code from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407620/134574

Answer (score 3):

It's often better to use `\linewidth` to measure the width of the current "block" rather than `\textwidth`. While you think `\textwidth` refers to the entire width of the text block and therefore `0.33\textwidth` should refer to (roughly) 1/3 of the text block, it doesn't. Under the `subfigure` environment, `\textwidth` is updated (actually setting it's contents inside a `minipage` which updates `\textwidth`) and doesn't represent what it stands for originally. You're effectively looking at an image that has a width of 0.33 x 0.33 x `\textwidth` or about 1/10 of the text width.

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:figure1}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:figure2}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:figure3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{This is a test.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```