# How is space factor calculated?

Tags: spacing, tex-core, plain-tex

In the following example, space factor is 1000 everywhere, so `\spaceskip` must never be used.
But why if we change it to `0pt` (after calling `\raggedright`),
the result is different?

```
\hsize=2in
\raggedright
%\spaceskip0pt

once upon a time in a distant galaxy there lived\end
```

Comment: See also the “How TeX turns spaces into glue” part of the answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412189/is-it-possible-to-have-non-french-spacing-without-extra-stretch/412196#412196 which answers your question (I think). The normal interword glue (which is `\spaceskip` if it has been set, else taken from the font) *is* always used for space factor < 2000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you probably suspected, the space factor has no role whatsoever here.

When `\spaceskip` is *nonzero* it is *always* used for interword space, unless the space factor is ≥ 2000, where `\xspaceskip` is used (if nonzero as well).

If you look at the definition of `\raggedright`

```
% plain.tex, line 647
\def\raggedright{\rightskip\z@ plus2em \spaceskip.3333em \xspaceskip.5em\relax}
```

So it's obvious that the output may change when you set back `\spaceskip` to zero.
The big difference is that the standard interword space has flexibility, whereas `\raggedright` sets `\spaceskip` with *no* flexibility.

### Test file

```
\hsize=2in
\raggedright
%\spaceskip0pt

\tracingoutput=1 \tracingonline=1
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen \showboxdepth=\maxdimen

\nopagenumbers

\hrule\bigskip

once upon a time in a distant galaxy there lived\end
```

### Without `\spaceskip=0pt`

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(667.20255+0.0)x144.54
.\vbox(0.0+0.0)x144.54, glue set 14.0fil
..\glue -22.5
..\hbox(8.5+0.0)x144.54, glue set 144.54fil
...\vbox(8.5+0.0)x0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x144.54, glue set 600.31366fill
..\glue(\topskip) 9.6
..\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
..\glue 12.0 plus 4.0 minus 4.0
..\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
..\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x144.54, glue set 0.4882
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
...\tenrm o
...\tenrm n
...\tenrm c
...\tenrm e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
...\tenrm u
...\tenrm p
...\kern0.27779
...\tenrm o
...\tenrm n
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
...\tenrm a
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
...\tenrm t
...\tenrm i
...\tenrm m
...\tenrm e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
...\tenrm i
...\tenrm n
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
...\tenrm a
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
...\tenrm d
...\tenrm i
...\tenrm s
...\discretionary
...\tenrm -
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 20.00003
..\penalty 400
..\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
..\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x144.54, glue set 45.34639fil
...\tenrm t
...\tenrm a
...\tenrm n
...\kern-0.27779
...\tenrm t
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
...\tenrm g
...\tenrm a
...\tenrm l
...\tenrm a
...\tenrm x
...\tenrm y
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
...\tenrm t
...\tenrm h
...\tenrm e
...\tenrm r
...\tenrm e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
...\tenrm l
...\tenrm i
...\tenrm v
...\kern-0.27779
...\tenrm e
...\tenrm d
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 20.00003
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x144.54
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
.\glue(\baselineskip) 24.0
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x144.54, glue set 144.54fil
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

### With `\spaceskip=0pt`

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(667.20255+0.0)x144.54
.\vbox(0.0+0.0)x144.54, glue set 14.0fil
..\glue -22.5
..\hbox(8.5+0.0)x144.54, glue set 144.54fil
...\vbox(8.5+0.0)x0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x144.54, glue set 600.31366fill
..\glue(\topskip) 9.6
..\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
..\glue 12.0 plus 4.0 minus 4.0
..\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
..\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x144.54, glue set - 0.74403
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
...\tenrm o
...\tenrm n
...\tenrm c
...\tenrm e
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm u
...\tenrm p
...\kern0.27779
...\tenrm o
...\tenrm n
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm a
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm t
...\tenrm i
...\tenrm m
...\tenrm e
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm i
...\tenrm n
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm a
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm d
...\tenrm i
...\tenrm s
...\tenrm t
...\tenrm a
...\tenrm n
...\kern-0.27779
...\tenrm t
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 20.00003
..\penalty 300
..\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
..\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x144.54, glue set 66.73427fil
...\tenrm g
...\tenrm a
...\tenrm l
...\tenrm a
...\tenrm x
...\tenrm y
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm t
...\tenrm h
...\tenrm e
...\tenrm r
...\tenrm e
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm l
...\tenrm i
...\tenrm v
...\kern-0.27779
...\tenrm e
...\tenrm d
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 20.00003
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x144.54
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
.\glue(\baselineskip) 24.0
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x144.54, glue set 144.54fil
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

Comment: As an aside: `\ ` (and `~`) behaves *as if* space factor is 1000, without changing it (i.e., `\ ' *always* uses normal space glue for the current font).

Comment: @IgorLiferenko That's right. In the *TeXbook*, this is documented on page 285 (Chapter 25: Summary of Horizontal Mode) and on page 290 (Chapter 26: Summary of Math Mode), rather than on page 76 (Chapter 12: Glue) where the rest of the stuff about space factor is documented. In the program, this is in ([section 1030](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=383)) in which you can see the same code for both `hmode + spacer : if space_factor = 1000 …` and for `hmode + ex_space, mmode + ex_space` (“ex_space” stands for the `\ ` primitive).