# Anonymous division in memoir with small caps

Tags: spacing, memoir, sections-paragraphs

I want to create "anonymous divisions" -- breaks in the text that do not have their own section titles.  I'm using the memoir class, and it provides `\plainbreak{}` and `\fancybreak{}` for this purpose.  But they don't do what I want: `\plainbreak` does not indicate a new division is started, and `\fancybreak` adds extra text. I'd like to indicate the new division by setting the first couple of words in small caps. Like this:

```
end of paragraph, followed by a couple of empty lines.


BEGINNING OF the new division, not indented, starting with small caps.
```

I've seen this in many books, and I'm surprised memoir does not provide it.

To be sure, I can achieve what I want with this:

```
\plainbreak{1}

\textsc{Beginning of} the new division...
```

But this is awkward, and not the LaTeX way (what if I want to change the spacing and font after creating dozens of these divisions?).  I then thought I should be able to simply use \paragraph with:

```
\setparaheadstyle{\normalsize\scshape}
```

But this leaves extra horizontal space after the \paragraph "title":

```
end of paragraph, followed by a couple of empty lines.


BEGINNING OF   the new division, but with extra space.
```

I found the `\setafterparaskip{}` command, but I don't know how to tell it to use interword spacing after `\paragraph{}`. E.g., `\setafterparaskip{\spaceskip}` does not work.

It's difficult to search for `\paragraph{}`, since most of the results discuss plain paragraphs, not the heading.

What is the best way to achieve what I want?

**EDIT**: there is of course a brute force method that does what I want:

```
\renewcommand*{\paragraph}[1]{\plainbreak{1}\textsc{#1}}
```

Are there any better ways?  Might this have any unexpected side-effects?

Answer (score 2):

Limitation:  It expects to find at least two more spaces in the input stream.

If you wish something that actually replaces `\plainbreak`, maybe this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand\plainbreak[1]{\par\vspace{#1\baselineskip}\Plainbreakaux}
\long\def\Plainbreakaux#1 #2 #3 {{\let\par\relax\noindent\scshape#2 #3} }
\begin{document}
\noindent end of paragraph, followed by a couple of empty lines.\plainbreak{1}


Beginning of the new division, not indented, starting with small caps.\plainbreak{2}

Also a new division\plainbreak{1}

A final division.

A regular paragraph boundary (indented).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about the example below. I added microtype to get letter spacing on the small caps (this is adjustable). The size of space is taken from this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229642/3929

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalsize\scshape\lsstyle}
\makeatletter
\normalfont
\@tempdima=\the\fontdimen2\font
\setafterparaskip{-\@tempdima} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}

end of paragraph, followed by a couple of empty lines.


\paragraph{Beginning of} the new division, not indented, starting with
small caps.

\end{document}
```

[image]